# How can I make a perfectly square plot with a colorbar in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

I am trying to create a contour plot (with colorbar) which has the contour plot perfectly square, for aesthetic/data interpretation reasons.

Example code:

```
x=-10:10;
y=-10:10;
[X Y] = meshgrid(x,y);
f = figure('Visible','off');
contour(X,Y,X.*Y,'Fill','on');
colorbar
x_size = 10;
y_size = 10;
set(f, 'PaperUnits', 'inches','PaperPosition',[0 0 x_size y_size]);
print(f, '-depsc2','notsquare.eps);
```

Is there a way to control the dimensions of just the contour plot region such that it will be perfectly square?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me (adding `axis equal`):

```
x=-10:10;
y=-10:10;
[X Y] = meshgrid(x,y);
f = figure('Visible','off');
contour(X,Y,X.*Y,'Fill','on');
colorbar, axis equal
x_size = 10;
y_size = 10;
set(f, 'PaperUnits', 'inches','PaperPosition',[0 0 x_size y_size]);
print(f, '-depsc2','square.eps');
```

Comment: Thanks!  Looking into it `axis equal` makes the data plotted square but leaves some whitespace within the plot box; `axis square` does just what I want.